# SQL query to get all values of first distinct (given) column values

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have the following sample data in my table:

```
ID  GRADE
1   54 
1   53  
1   52
2   78  
2   75 
2   74 
3   43 
3   42
3   41
```

This is gotten from the query: "SELECT ID,GRADE FROM TABLE ORDER BY GRADE DESC;" The ID is not a primary key.

I want to obtain the data like this:

```
ID  GRADE
1   54
2   78
3   43
```

That is, I want to get the value of all records that are the first distinct ones in terms of the ID.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what defines "first" in an RDBM set?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: The order of the rows is not guaranteed unless you have a primary key or date field to sort by...

Comment: You either need to add a third column to your data, or tell us how you ordered this data.  The term "first" is ambiguous without this information.

Comment: Edited, the Grade field is sorted in descending order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this simple `group by` :

```
select ID, max(GRADE) 
from TABLE 
group by ID
order by ID
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I knew it was just simple. Thanks!